# ActiveRecord Relation to hash output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am once again banging my head upon ActiveRecord::Relation.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
current_user.jobs.includes(:employee).map {|c| { name: "#{c.employee.name}, hire_date: c.employee.hire_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") } }
```

So, I have a current_user which has many jobs.  I want to return all of them that include an employee.  Based on this ActiveRecord Relation I want to get worker's name and hire date based on this relation.  However, when I do this I get the dreaded error:

NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass.

I have also tried to convert the ActiveRecord relation to an array, hash and to json.  All of these have returned the same error when trying to get the name.

All I am trying to do is to take the collection of:

current_user.jobs.includes(:employee) and to iterate over that relation and create an array of hashes based on the returned data.

Any ideas or pushes in the right direction on this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.employee` method instead of `.worker` — as you are including `employee` model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you `includes` `:employee` but reference `:worker` but in any case the expression `current_user.jobs` is giving you an iteration over jobs, so I'd be tempted to call each element `j`.  No big deal.  Not sure why you have that interpolation there, that's not needed.

This should work...

```
city_date_hash = current_user.jobs.includes(:employee).map {|j| { city: j.employee.name, hire_date: j.employee.hire_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") } }
```

Also, I'm not sure why the `employee.name` is under the key `:city`... I'd probably have used `:name` or `:employee_name`

Comment: Steve, you are correct, I was in between editing/working on the code and put in the wrong code in my question.  I edited my question.  I actually did have something similar to what you put in there and it doesn't work.  It throws the "NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" error as I mentioned.  See my updated question for what I had.

Comment: I just figured it out.  I have a nil object when I am iterating over the collection.  So what you have does work until I hit up against my nil object that is being returned.